Is there a way to make the Angular extract-i18n function create a single xlf file output for all projects in a monorepo?
I have a mono repo with a few applications and several libraries. Everything is Angular based Typescript. I have functioning extract-i18n tooling for each application, which pulls in library strings to translate as needed. This works ok in that it generates separate xlf files for each of my languages for each application separately.
I'm wondering if it is possible, or even makes sense, to extract everything into a single set of xlf files. Meaning, I want to run the extract command once on the monorepo, have it generate xlf files for each language I support, but each of those xlf files covers the entire monorepo, not just a single project within it.
I've just begun researching this problem. It seems feasible to solve, but I have yet to find anyone asking the same question.
I plan on manipulating the build targets, possibly creating a tools library project to house one that pulls in everything. I'll post an answer to this question if that solves it.
